# How to handle extra Square brackets in SQL column name

Tags: sql-server

I need to pass Column name as [ID-ColumnName] as column name in order by for a table.

Ex:

```
Select [ID-ColumnName],[ID2-ColumnName2] FROM TABLE1 ORDER BY [ID-ColumnName]
```

Problem is if the ColumnName which is dynamic name comes with one opening/closing square brackets e.g Column[Name or Column]Name

In this scenario the SQL statement is breaking; Problem is I dont know how many such open/close square brackets can come.

Wrapping the column name with square brackets is mandatory in my scenario.

Please help me handling this scenario.

Comment: can you please write your attempted code

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454597/how-do-i-query-column-names-that-contain-square-brackets

Comment: Are you looking for [`QUOTENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I had tried that but the in some of my scenarios the SQL statement QUOTENAME('SQL') works and in some scenarios it required to be given as QUOTENAME(SQL) and hence I am not able to take advantage of this as the QUOTENAME() will be passed from Dot Net code

Answer (score 2):

All,

I was able to solve the problem like given below:

Create a table having square brackets in name (You can choose to have any combination of open/close brackets or single open/close).

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [OF-[Test [Name]]]]] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

And the Prepare the Dynamic Query and use `QUOTENAME()` function as suggested by @Damien_The_Unbeliever; but make sure the `QUOTENAME()` function should not be given as string; post that execute the Query.

```
DECLARE @orderBy NVARCHAR(MAX),@sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @orderBy = N' ORDER BY '+QUOTENAME('OF-[Test [Name]]')+' ASC'
SET @sql=N'select '+QUOTENAME('OF-[Test [Name]]')+' from TestTable'
--PRINT(@sql +@orderBy)
EXEC(@sql +@orderBy)
```

Thanks for all your help & suggestions.